# How do I see student A's progress in a specific Course? if I add progress it adds it to the whole course instead of only student A

Tags: java, class

I have 2 classes, Student and Course. I want to be able to add progress to a course a student follows and see how much progress said student has in specific courses.

Ex:

```
John.addProgress(Programming, 20);
John.seeProgress(Programming); //(Result = 20)
```

The problem starts when I create multiple Students. If I add another student named Mike and ask for his progress in programming. I still get as a result 20, because i added 20 progress with John.

```
John.addProgress(Programming, 20);
John.seeProgress(Programming);  //(result = 20)
Mike.seeProgress(Programming); //(result = 20, but result has to be 0)
```

This feels like such a simple problem with an easy solution, but I just can't figure it out for some reason.

```
public class Course {

   private int percentage;
   private String name;

   public Course(String name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.percentage = 0;
   }

   public void addProgress(int amount) {
       this.percentage += amount;
   }

   public int seeProgress() {
       return this.percentage;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return this.name;
   }

}
```

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;
    private int percentage;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        this.courses.add(course);
    }

    public void seeCourses() {
        for (Course i : courses) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }

    public void addProgress(Course course, int amount) {
        course.addProgress(20);
    }

    public int seeProgress(Course course) {
        return course.seeProgress();
    }


}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course programming = new Course("Programming");
        Course english = new Course("English");

        Student john = new Student("John");
        Student mike = new Student("Mike");

        john.addProgress(english, 20);
        System.out.println("John's progress: " + john.seeProgress(english)); 
        System.out.println("Mike's progress: " + mike.seeProgress(english));

    }
}
```

The result i'm getting is:

```
John's progress: 20
Mike's progress: 20
```

But the result i want is:

```
John's progress: 20
Mike's progress: 0
```

I've tried to look online for some help, but I couldn't really find anything useful, mostly because I also don't really know how to effectively look this problem up.

Comment: Your class structures could be improved. A course could have a Map field of students that holds the value of each student's progress, e.g., `Map<Student, Integer> studentProgress = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: you are adding 20 to the course in general without the student, and you are passing the same course when calling mike.seeProgress

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Hovercraft Full Of Eels! I've added a hashmap to Course and removed everything that has to do with progress from Student and now it works!

Code for anyone that wants to see:

```
public class Course {

   private int percentage;
    private String name;
    private Map<Student,Integer> students;

    public Course(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.percentage = 0;
        this.students = new HashMap();
    }

    public void addProgress(Student student, int amount) {
       students.put(student, students.get(student) + amount);
    }

    public void addStudents(Student student) {
        students.put(student, 0);
    }

    public int seeProgress(Student student) {
        return students.get(student);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

.

```
   public class Student {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;
    

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        this.courses.add(course);
    }

    public void seeCourses() {
        for (Course i : courses) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }

}
```

.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course programming = new Course("Programming");
        Course english = new Course("English");

        Student john = new Student("John");
        Student mike = new Student("Mike");
        programming.addStudents(mike);
        programming.addStudents(john);
        programming.addProgress(mike, 20);
        System.out.println("John's progress: " + 
        programming.seeProgress(john));

        System.out.println("Mike's progress: " + 
        programming.seeProgress(mike));
    }
}
```